# String.format java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = '#'

Tags: java, regex, string, string-formatting

I have a String with sql query:

```
String string = "SELECT 1 FROM store WHERE merch_name like '%#1%'";
```

But later in code,I do String.format on that srting, for example:

```
String s1 = String.format(
                        string ,
                        ruleBody.getDateTimeStartValue()
                        }
```

and that's give me exception:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException:  Flags = '#'
```

I think that I need add '%' begore  '#" char, but how can  I check if any of special character exists in my string('$','@','*' for example), and will add '%' before them , to avoid that exception?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use string concatenation to build the query. Why don't you use prepared statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using regular expression check special character present or not.

```
String query = "SELECT 1 FROM store WHERE merch_name like '%#1%'";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
    boolean b = m.find();

    String string = null;

    if (b){
        // escape special character with `%`            
        string = "SELECT 1 FROM store WHERE merch_name like '%%#1%'";
    }else{
        string = query;
    }
```

Then use `string` to execute query.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the % letter, because String.format thinks you want to specify something there. Like this:

```
String string = "SELECT 1 FROM store WHERE merch_name like '%%#1%'";
```

Comment: thx for feedback, but my main trouble in " but how can I check if any of special character exists in my string('$','@','*' for example), and will add escape the % letter before them , to avoid that exception?"